# Call an existing php variable by concatenating two strings

Tags: php

I have these seven php variables:

```
$dataA = 1;
$targetA = 2;
$dataB = 3;
$targetB = 4;
$dataC = 5;
$targetC = 6;
results = array('A','B','C');
```

I would like to loop through the results array and pass the corresponding variables to a function.

```
foreach($results as $value) {
    $data = '$data'.$value;
    $target = '$target'.$value;
    buildOutput('$data'.$value,'$target'.$value); 
}

// example, first time thru, wish to pass $dataA variable and $targetA variable

function buildOutput($data,$target) {
    echo "data=$data,target=$target<br>"; // echo's strings "$dataA" and "$targetA"
}
```

I cannot figure out how to declare the variables. Or if this is even possible.

I have more than just $data and $target variables, but I simplified down to two for the question.

Comment: Please use arrays to store values: `array('A' => ['data' => 1, 'target' => 2]); // etc`

Comment: I didn't wish to make the example complicated, but the $data's are associative arrays. The $target's are not. But I will re-think this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using it, but try this:

```
$dataA = 1;
$targetA = 2;
$dataB = 3;
$targetB = 4;
$dataC = 5;
$targetC = 6;

$results = array('A','B','C');

foreach($results as $value) {
  buildOutput(${'data'.$value}, ${'target'.$value}); 
}

function buildOutput($data, $target) {
  echo "data=$data,target=$target<br>";
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. But why "would not recommend"? I'm only using this on my localhost.

Comment: im not recommend it, because it could break your code with wrong data/values, or cause some unexpected behavior. I would suggest to use Arrays, if possible. If only using for yourself, its ok, i guess.